# how to prevent the click event of the parent when its children is being dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is a sample code:

```
$('.bmc-div').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // console.log(e.target);
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('my-sticky')) {

    } else {
        canvas.add_sticky($(this));
    }
});

$('.bmc-div .sticky_container').sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,  
    helper: 'clone',
    // handle: ".element-handler",
    connectWith: '.bmc-div .sticky_container',
    scroll: true,
    cancel: null,
    opacity: 0.7,
    // axis: 'y',
    items: ".my-sticky",
    placeholder : "sticky-placeholder",
    containment: "#main",
    zIndex: 9999,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        // update_sortable_position();
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Here is the HTML Code for the question:

```
 <div id="bmc-rs" class="col-sm-12 bmc-div">
        <div class='bmc-row'>
             <p style='margin: 0px;'><span class="grid-label">Revenue Streams              </span><span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="sticky_container">
                <div class="my-sticky" style="display: block;">Sample Sticky</div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that the child element will be dragged but when stopped, it will still trigger the click event of the parent container.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt I just added the HTML Code.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop propagation on your `draggable` element's `mousedown` event:

```
$('.sticky_container').mousedown(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: thanks.. it worked! I just changed it to delegate.. $('body').delegate('.sticky_container','.mousedown', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});